# Beginner Macro to Copy and Paste columns

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a Macro where the users can add more users into the Spreadsheet on 'Sheet 1', that will then insert more columns into 'Sheet 2' that is the same as the previous columns so all the formatting stays same.

I've already got the code to add more rows on Sheet 1 into the table but struggling to then also Copy the columns in Sheet 2 and insert it to the right.

Any Help would be great please.

Screenshots To Help:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/2pu7okcxjk2h79m/Advisor.png?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/kvhi4p4dn6zcp6x/Setup.png?dl=0

Wouldn't let me post pictures directly as need more rep :/

In the Setup page, the aim is to click the Plus, it will add a row
In the Advisor page, its to copy and insert the Columns (Q:U) infront of V without breaking the total sum code

Answer (score 0):

Use the following subroutine to copy a col for Sheet1 to Sheet2. The ColId is the the index of the column.

```
Sub CopyColumnsFromSheet1ToSheet2()
Dim ColId As Long
'1 is Col A
ColId = 1
Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(ColId).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Columns(ColId)
End Sub
```

Comment: The aim is on Sheet 1 is to add new row and at the same time on Sheet 2 copy Columns Q to U and insert them before V. Then everytime a new row is added on sheet 1 this then again adds the columns.

Comment: Can you illustrate with a screenshot?

Comment: Have posted pictures along with main question